# How do I 'hook' into the requested page with the Express Framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side

I have this example code from the express tutorial pages.

```
app.use(express.static('/path/to/html/files'));
```

However, in my application, some of the requested pages should only be generated on demand.
So, I want the filename the user needs, pass it to a program running in the background (I do not want to spawn this process repeatedly as it takes some time to initialize) and then wait for it to signal that my file is available.

What is the recommended way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

See [`app.get()`](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) in the Express documentation.  For ease of programming, you probably want to use different paths for statically served files vs. dynamically built files.  It just makes managing the routes a lot easier.

```
app.get("/mydynamicfile", function(req, res) {
    // code here to create the response for this route
    res.send(...);
});
```

Comment: My static pages would have hyperlinks to get some of the dynamic data. How should I pass this link info to the server ?

Comment: @manasij7479 - I do not understand what your comment means.  Static pages are just files of HTML, CSS and Javascript, nothing more.  Static pages, once loaded into the browser, can run Ajax calls that request data from the server if that's perhaps what you mean.

Comment: I am not trying to make ajax calls, I have links in the static page, say..to foo.html which may not exist yet.  
When the server receives this request, I want it to create this file and then serve it.

Comment: @manasij7479 - that's exactly what my answer shows with `app.get()`.

Comment: But I don't know the route in advance. I want to pass that as a string to another process which generates the files.

Comment: @manasij7479 - then you would typically use a common prefix to the route for all of these particular type of routes.  You would create a generic `app.get()` handler for that common prefix and that handler could then examine the rest of the route to determine what content to generate.  If your scheme fits in to a common set of parameters, you can even place the parameters at specific points in the URL and have express parse these parameters for you.  So, you could have a handler for `"/custom/*"` and it would get called for `"/custom/a/b/c"` and you could then examine the details of the URL.

Comment: @manasij7479 - or you could design a middleware handle that would see all requests and decide what to do.  Depending upon the exact details of what you're trying to do, there are many, many different options.

Comment: Could you elaborate about the parameter thing ? My links would typically look like: "prefix/DF34JJQ2JAS.html" .
This DF34JJQ2JAS is what the server needs to generate the file.

Comment: @manasij7479 - there's a lot written about how to use parameters in URLs with Express [on their site](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req).  It would make a lot more sense for you to educate yourself there and then come back here if you can't figure something in the doc out and have a much more specific question.  Simple example here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req